# Why can I add nodes to the end but not the start of this list?

Tags: c, list

The following works fine where I add a new node to the end of my list:

```
typedef struct node* edge;
struct node
{
   int data;
   edge next;
};

void add(edge start, int val)
{
   edge n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   n->data = val;
   n->next = NULL;

   while (start->next)
      start = start->next;

   start->next = n;
}
```

however, if I change the body of `add()` to:

```
edge n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n->data = val;
n->next = start;

start = n;
```

nothing is added.

I was expecting the new node to become the new start of my list, with the previous start as the 2nd in line. Why does the first implementation work as expected and not the second? What is the best way to implement the functionality I was expecting from the second method, can it be done with the void function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because pointers are passed by value, meaning that when you do

```
start = n;
```

only the local copy of the pointer that you passed is getting changed. To fix this, pass start by pointer to pointer:

```
void add(edge* start, int val)
{
    edge n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->data = val;
    n->next = *start;

    *start = n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that variables in C are passed "by value" and not "by reference". So, when you set `start = n` in your second code, that change is not reflected in any other place in your code. Instead, do this:

```
edge add(edge start, int val)
{
   edge n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   n->data = val;
   n->next = start;
   return n;
}
```

Or, for a by-reference solution:

```
void add(edge* start, int val)
{
   edge n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   n->data = val;
   n->next = *start;
   *start = n;
}
```

Using a pointer here gives you a reference to an `edge`, which you can then modify both within the function and in the caller. (But, if you change the value of the pointer "start" without dereferencing it, note that that change is local to the function.)

Comment: Correct, that was poor phrasing on my part. I will edit to update, thanks.